# AWS SAM: How to locally invoke all Node.js functions instead one by one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I am developing a REST API with `AWS Lambda`, `API Gateway`, `RDS (MySQL)`. I am using `Node.js`. I am also using `AWS SAM` tool.

In my API I have lambda functions that accept URL parameters and that do not accept them.

I noticed that I can deploy these to AWS without an issue, and then execute from `POSTMAN`.

However when I try to locally run them, I am running into problems.

1. When I execute `sam local invoke`, it says `Error: You must provide a function logical ID when there are more than one functions in your template.` So I had to execute them one by one, like `sam local invoke FunctionName`
2. When I try to invoke a function that accepts URL parameters, it says `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'event.queryStringParameters' as it is undefined.` Here the `id` is the name of the URL Param.

So,

1. How can I locally invoke all node.js functions, instead of one by one?
2. How can I make sure that functions with URL Params also can be locally invoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Node.JS, it is not possible to locally invoke all at once. `sam local invoke FUNCTION_NAME` is the way to go.

Since the question is about a REST API, if you want to check how thE rest api is working, all you have to do is this

```
sam build
sam local start-api
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally run the following without build since it helps to view the changes during development:

```
sam local start-api 2>&1 | tr “\r” “\n”
```